# How to launch a process after some period of inactivity in Windows?

Tags: windows

Is there a Windows functionality (reg entry, job, etc) that allows me to launch a process after some period of inactivity (i.e. no user keyboard/mouse input) in a Windows session?

I don't want the process to be always running e.g. running it at startup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Windows Vista/2008 and later, there is an "On idle" trigger for tasks in the task scheduler.  Additionally, you could schedule on "On workstation lock" so that when you step away and lock the screen the task is started.